# My regex works in online editor but in FireBug it makes the browser to crash

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written the following regex to catch anything within two parenthesis of a text:

```
var rule = /[a-zA-Z0-9]*(\(+[a-zA-Z\s0-9]*\))*[a-zA-Z0-9\s]/;
```

It works in this website: http://regex101.com/ (javascript section)

Look the right side of the window and you see the bottom section shows the matched string which is what I want.

But in firebug when I execute the following code it crashes. Why? how then should I catch the group in parenthesis?

```
var rule = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*(\(+[a-zA-Z\s0-9]*\))*[a-zA-Z0-9\s\,]*/;

var str = "He left us (with anger), but came back all cool and modest.";

var res = "";

while((res = rule.exec(str)) !== null)
{
   console.log("Good");
}

console.log(res);
```

Or maybe I'm totally wrong and am missing something?

Comment: Hint: replace the while loop with `console.log( rule.exec(str) ); console.log( rule.exec(str) );` and see what the output is.

Comment: Looks like your while loop is infinite to me.

Comment: Unrelated but you may be able to simplify your regex  e.g. [^()]*\(([^)]*)\)[^()]*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"But in firebug when I execute the following code it crashes. Why?"*

To use `.exec()` in a loop like that, the regex must be global. Otherwise it's just going to keep getting the first match, resulting in an infinite loop.

```
// make it global ------------------------------------------------v
var rule = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*(\(+[a-zA-Z\s0-9]*\))*[a-zA-Z0-9\s\,]*/g;
```

When global, the regex object becomes stateful, and each subsequent `.exec()` will begin from the character after the last match.

When there are finally no matches left, it'll return `null`, breaking the loop.

---

As others pointed out in the comments, the leading `^` will guarantee only one match *(without the `m` modifier anyway)*, so you'll probably want to remove that. It's not the cause of the crash though.

Comment: Also, it will never match more than once because of the `^` anchor at the beginning.

Comment: What about the `^` anchor in the regex?

Comment: @Juhana, Unihedron: That's a good point and needs to be corrected if there are to be multiple matches. I'm just answering why it causes a crash.

Comment: then it returns an array of three elements, with one of them is what I want, why it returns the other two? I need only parenthesis.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi: That's just how it works, the first member in the Array is the full match, and the rest are the groups. For your example, there should only be two members in the Array, so you need to grab the second member *(index `1`)*.